# RecyclerView Problems With The Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Alright I'm trying to display data called by an api on a recyclerview and I get the error. It has nothing to do with butterknife I think. Please help.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at com.example.myflickrproject.PhotoDisplayView.onCreate(PhotoDisplayView.java:40)

```
public class PhotoDisplayView extends AppCompatActivity { //implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
    @BindView(R.id.recView)
    RecyclerView rViewDis;

    @BindView(R.id.addToDatabse)
    Button download;

    @BindView(R.id.backButton)
    Button goBack;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_display_view);
        System.out.println("My photolist is " + DataCollection.photoList);
        rViewDis.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        PhotoAdapter myAdapter = new PhotoAdapter(this, DataCollection.photoList);
        rViewDis.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

    }



    @OnClick({R.id.addToDatabse, R.id.backButton})
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int btns = v.getId();
        switch (btns) {
            case R.id.addToDatabse:
                addToDatabse();
                break;
            case R.id.backButton:
                backToMenu();
                break;


        }
    }

    public void addToDatabse() {

    }

    public void backToMenu() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to do `findViewById()` in your `rViewDis`

Comment: ButterKnife.bind(this); should be set first before using recycler view for adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Bind your views after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_display_view);`
So, your code should be like this 
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_display_view);
 ButterKnife.bind(this);`